# Finding list of unique objects with a tolerance

Tags: c#, distinct

I have a list of points from which I want to extract only the unique elements. The point class is as follows

```
class Point
{
   double X;
   double Y;
   double Z;
}
```

now two points for example p1(1,2,3) and p2(1.01,2,3.01) should be considered as same point. that is some tolerance is there. Now because of the tolerance I am not able to use c# distinct()  method or any of the functions that use hascode. Is there any possible way by which I can get the the unique list with out having to use Bruteforce method and which will identify p1 and p2 as same point and will only keep one of them in the unique list

Comment: Implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface, override the two methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, its explained [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: You can as well use a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) and the [`Distinct<T>(IEqualityComparer<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) overload.

Comment: but how will I write a gethashcode which will allow tolerance?

Comment: @nandini banerjee: `GetHashCode() => 0;` is *ugly*, *good for nothing*, but a *correct* implementation of hash function (which allows tolerance). The real problem is that we *can't implement* `Equals` method

Comment: As grouping by equivalence is impossible (clearly shown by @DmitryBychenko), what you are searching for is a "clustering algorithm". There are some commonly used in data analysis, maybe you can have a look there.

Comment: @nandinibanerjee - Dmitry has given you a wonderful explanation as to why you can't do what you're asking for. It's now a matter of you looking for another solution to your problem at hand that doesn't involve a fuzzy equals. What were you hoping to do?

Answer (score 3):

Alas, it's *not possible* even in the simplest `1d` case (let `Y` and `Z` be equal for all the points).
We can prove it by contradiction; let `e` be a positive *tolerance*, which means that

```
 p1 ~ p2
```

whenever

```
 |p1.X - p2.X| <= e
```

Every equality relation must meet three properties:

1. Reflexive: `A ~ A`
2. Symmetric: if `A ~ B` then `B ~ A`
3. Transitive: if `A ~ B` and `B ~ C` then `A ~ C`

There are no problems with 1st and 2nd properties, but we *can't meet* the 3d one: counter example is
three points `A, B, C` such that

```
B.X = A.X + e
C.X = B.X + e = A.X + 2 * e
```

So we have

```
|A.X - B.X| = e <= e, so A ~ B
|B.X - C.X| = e <= e, so B ~ C
```

However

```
|A.X - C.X| = 2 * e > e, so A !~ C
```

**Edit:** You can try *scaling* as a *partial* solution. Points are equal if they are in the same (hyper-)*cube* `e * e * ... * e` where scale factor `e` is some kind of "tolerance". So, for

```
class Point
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
}
```

We can implement an equality comparer like this:

```
public class PointEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point> {
  private double m_Scale;

  private long Scale(double value) => (long)Math.Round(value / m_Scale);

  public PointEqualityComparer(double scale) {
    m_Scale = scale > 0
      ? scale
      : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(scale));
  }

  public bool Equals(Point left, Point right) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
      return true;
    else if (null == left || null == right)
      return false;

    return Scale(left.X) == Scale(right.X) &&
           Scale(left.Y) == Scale(right.Y) &&
           Scale(left.Z) == Scale(right.Z);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Point obj) => obj == null
    ? 0
    : Scale(obj.X).GetHashCode() ^ 
      Scale(obj.Y).GetHashCode() ^ 
      Scale(obj.Z).GetHashCode();
}
```

Usage

```
List<Point> original = ...

List<Point> unique = original
  .Distinct(new PointEqualityComparer(1e-3))
  .ToList();
```

Another popular approach - *clustering* - can be, howw=ever, much difficult to implement. First, you group points into clusters (which can be *huge*, of different shapes etc.) then take "typical representatives" from each cluster (say, all all point which are on the border of their cluster).